# Create Time-Series Dataframe for Regression in Python

Tags: python, dataframe, time-series, regression

I have a crime dataset where each row is a recorded crime, and the relevant columns are Date, Crime Type, District.

Here is an example with only 2 Districts and 2 Crime Types over a week:

[image]

I want to expand it to a dataframe that can be used to run regressions. In this simple example, I need the columns to be Date, District, Murder, Theft. Each District would have a different row for each date in the range, and the crime type categories would be the number of that crimes committed on that Date in that District

Here is the final dataframe:

[image]

I need - a time series where #Rows = #Districts * #Dates, and there is a column for each crime type

Are there any good ways to make this without looping through the dataframes?

I can create the date list like this:

```
datelist = pd.date_range(start='01-01-2011', end='12-31-2015', freq='1d')
```

But how do I merge that with my other dataframe and create the columns described above?

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer my own question here. I think I figured it out, but would appreciate any input on my method. I was able to do it without looping, but rather using pivot_table and merge.

Import packages:

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import numpy as np
```

Import crime dataset:

```
crime_df = pd.read_csv("/Users/howard/Crime_Data.csv")
```

Create a list of dates in the range:

```
datelist = pd.date_range(start='01-01-2011', end='12-31-2015', freq='1d')
```

Create variables for the length of this date list and length of unique districts list:

```
nd = len(datelist)
nu = len(df_crime['District'].unique())
```

Create dataframe combining dates and districts:

```
date_df = pd.DataFrame({'District':df_crime['District'].unique().tolist()*nd, 'Date':np.repeat(datelist,nu)})
```

Now we turn to our crime dataset.

I added a column of 1s to have something to sum in the next step:

```
crime_df["ones"] = 1
```

Next we take our crime data and put it in wide form using Pandas pivot_table:

```
crime_df = pd.pivot_table(crime_df,index=["District","Date"], columns="Crime Type", aggfunc="sum")
```

This gave me stacked-level columns and an unnecessary index, so I removed them with the following:

```
crime_df.columns.droplevel()

crime_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

The final step is to merge the two datasets. I want to put date_df first and merge on that because it includes all the dates in the range and all the districts included for each date. Thus, this uses a Left merge.

```
final_df = pd.merge(date_df, crime_df, on=["Date", "District"],how="left")
```

Now I can finish by filling in NaN with 0s

```
final_df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Our final dataframe is in the correct form to do time series analyses - regressions, plotting, etc. Many of the plots in matplotlib.pyplot that I use are easier to make if the date column is the index. This can be done like this:

```
df_final = df_final.set_index(['Date'])
```

That's it! Hope this helps others and please comment on any way to improve.